# div positioning, odd behavior

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a single page web design, i want to use hrefs with # to link different places in the same archive, the desired functionality is to move to the link location when clicking, this works BUT, only if i float left A,B divs,
i dont understand this, A and B divs are containing other stuff already, but if i dont put the float: left in the css, links dont work. Why is that?

```css
#A,
#B {
  float: left;
}
.cont1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: #2077a5;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#A">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#B">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="A">
  <div id="about" class="cont1">
    About page content goes here.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="B">
  <div id="portfolio" class="cont1">
    Portfolio page content goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Wow, that are some fast answers, thanks a lot, i think im not being understood, my question is WHY if i dont set any style for A and B divs links dont work, dont they expand a locate automatically by being containers of style defined divs?

Comment: if your put the float:left to the divs, the intern anchors href="#..." doesn't make sence anymore. Just remove the floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using the `float:left;` for `#A` and `#B`, add `clear:both;`  to that first rule to have them NOT begin at the same line(in which case the local anchors wouldn't make any sense):

```
#A,
#B {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRRxGy

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT AND EDIT OF QUESTION:

To try and see, delete the float for A and B (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwwEAr) and have a look at it in the developer tools: Both #A and 'B will have a size of 1406 x 0 (!) and will be at the very same position.

That's because DIVs that only contain floated elements will have no "official" height (i.e. they won't wrap their actual contents) - search for questions about floating to get examples. So vertically the "unfloated" #A and #B are at the same height, which is why the links lead to the same scroll position. Strange stuff, but it all has to do with floated elements and how floating elements affects the height of their containers.

Comment: i dont insist, originally i was not setting the style for A and B, but if i dont set it, links dont work! question is... why? i just edited the question

Comment: please have a look at the addition to my answer - it was to long for a comment

Comment: thanks man! this is the answer i was looking for, really helpful!

Comment: I think i did. I upvoted it. But im a new user here and i think my votes still dont fully work.

Comment: upvoting and "accepting as the correct answer" are two different things, but never mind...

Comment: uhm, im such a noob here, just marked the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

problem is you set .cont1 class for both section and make them float left with a height of 1500px. try with this css

```
 #A, #B {
  min-width: 100%;

}

.cont1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2077a5;
  }
```

you can use the id="about" and id="portfolio" for link so you don't need the extra div #A , B

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>


 <div id="about" class="cont1">
  About page content goes here. 
 </div>    



 <div id="portfolio" class="cont1">
   Portfolio page content goes here. 
 </div>

.cont1 {
width: 100%;
height: 1500px;
background-color: #2077a5;
float: left;
 }
```

Comment: you can use the id="about" and id="portfolio" for link so you don't need the extra div #A , B <<< yes i did that before, and it works, but i want to know why my example doesnt, i mean, is like if u dont define the css for de A and B divs, they behaivor is very strange cause, the inside DIV locate right, but A and B work as if they are locked in the top part of the page space

Comment: because you dont set the width or margin that makes those section separate from each other  .. thats why .

Comment: if dont use css for #A and #B they also work. if you float them left they place side by side without any gap thats also work. bt at the same position